# How can i append table data value in ng-repeat using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two table. dynamicaly data will come for `table one` after I click the  dynamic table data button. after I click the `done` button I want to 
append the data in `$scope.notiData`.
now after I click `done` button `$scope.notiData` data is gone. every time data is coming from `tableTwo` what is there in presently. so how can i use concat Iin `$scope.notiData`.please help.
http://jsfiddle.net/A6bt3/127/

**Js**

```
   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   function checkBoxCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.notiData = [];
   $scope.tableOne = [{
        firstname: 'robert',
        value: 'a'
    }, {
        firstname: 'raman',
        value: 'b'
    }, {
        firstname: 'kavi',
        value: 'c'
    }, {
        firstname: 'rorank',
        value: 'd'
    }
];
    $scope.tableOne1 = [{
        firstname: 'robvzxcvert',
        value: 'a'
    }, {
        firstname: 'ramsdgan',
        value: 'b'
    }, {
        firstname: 'kasdgsdgvi',
        value: 'c'
    }, {
        firstname: 'rordggank',
        value: 'd'
    }
];
$scope.tableTwo = [];//the table to be submitted
function removeitems(tableRef) { //revmove items from tableRef
    var i;
    for (i = tableRef.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        if (tableRef[i].checked) {
            tableRef.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
$scope.btnRight = function () {
   //Loop through tableone
    $scope.tableOne.forEach(function (item, i) {
       // if item is checked add to tabletwo
        if (item.checked) {
            $scope.tableTwo.push(item);
        }
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableOne);
}
$scope.btnAllRight = function () {
    $scope.tableOne.forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.checked = true;
        $scope.tableTwo.push(item);
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableOne);
}
$scope.btnLeft = function () {
    $scope.tableTwo.forEach(function (item, i) {
        if (item.checked) {
            $scope.tableOne.push(item);
        }
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableTwo);
}
$scope.btnAllLeft = function () {
    $scope.tableTwo.forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.checked = true;
        $scope.tableOne.push(item);
    })
    removeitems($scope.tableTwo);
}
$scope.done = function () {
      angular.extend($scope.notiData, $scope.tableTwo);
     $scope.tableTwo = [];
}
$scope.removeRow = function (item) {
    var index = $scope.notiData.indexOf(item);
    $scope.notiData.splice(index, 1); 
}
 $scope.dynamicTable= function () {  
       $scope.tableOne1.forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.checked = true;
        $scope.tableOne.push(item);
    })
   } 
  };
```

Comment: check your browser console, it said "duplicate in ng-repeat use track by", by chaging the expression to `ng-repeat="data in notiData track by firstname"` I have something working, not sure it has the behaviour wanted though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to append the data in `$scope.notiData`. now after I click  done button `$scope.notiData` data is gone

The `angular.extend` replaces existing entries. To append, use [array.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
$scope.done = function () {
     //angular.extend($scope.notiData, $scope.tableTwo);
     $scope.notiData = $scope.notiData.concat($scope.tableTwo);
     $scope.tableTwo = [];
}
```

Also to avoid `duplicate in ng-repeat use track by` errors, use [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to push items:

```
$scope.dynamicTable= function () {  
    $scope.tableOne1.forEach(function (item, i) {
        item.checked = true;
        //$scope.tableOne.push(item);
        $scope.tableOne.push(angular.copy(item));
    }); 
};
```

The `ng-repeat` directive tracks array objects by reference. Pushing duplicate objects will result in tracking errors. The `angular.copy` will create a new unique object reference for the item and will avoid the tracking errors.

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2fvt3c1/).

Comment: please remove duplicate data from ng-repeat:http://jsfiddle.net/j2fvt3c1/2/